# How do I solve gallery scroll stuttering in a landscape-oriented UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, performance, uiimagepickercontroller

I have tried a couple of different methods for presenting a landscape-oriented UIImagePickerController in a landscape-only app (not by my choice) I'm working on.

When I (successfully) present the gallery in landscape format and scroll through the images, there is a truly horrible stutter!

The current technique I am using is this:

```
- (void)presentImagePickerController:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if (isDeviceIPad) {
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        picker.preferredContentSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    }

    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentViewController:picker
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

I cannot go with a solution which uses private interfaces, since the app has to pass App Store review.  I'd prefer not to use a third-party library, since my boss is against that idea.

My iPad is a 3rd generation, model MD334LL/A that's running iOS 8.1.

Comment: iPad 3 has performance problems. Its hardware is simply too slow for its retina display.

Comment: The gallery scrolls very smoothly on my iPad when it's in portrait.

Comment: But it has less space for images that way.

Answer (score 0):

From the UIImagePickerController class reference found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html

On iPad, the correct way to present an image picker depends on its source type, as summarized in this table:

Camera: Use full screen

Photo Library: Must use a popover

Saved Photos Album: Must use a popover

**Answer:** Since I want to present the Saved Photos Album, I need to present the picker by using a popover.

```
- (void)presentImagePickerController:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    if (isDeviceIPad() && sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum) {
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

        UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = picker.popoverPresentationController;
        presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
        presentationController.sourceView = self.presentPickerButton;
        presentationController.sourceRect = self.presentPickerButton.bounds;
    }

    [self presentViewController:picker
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```